# how to execute bash scripts via cgi

Tags: bash, cgi

I'm trying to call a bash script from within a webpage page using cgi. I have it partially working in that echo commands appear to work but other commands don't.

I'm using lighttpd and I have a file cgi.sh, which calls demo_start.sh

cat /srv/http/cgi.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. includes/srv/http/demo_start.sh
/usr/bin/bash /srv/http/demo_start.sh
```

cat /srv/http/demo_start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"

ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'>/srv/http/ip.txt
file="/srv/http/ip.txt"
ip_address=$(cat ${file})

echo ${ip_address}

file="/srv/http/demo_count.txt"
count=$(cat ${file})

((count++))
echo ${count} > ${file}

echo Demo started ${count} times

sed -i".bak" '$d' /srv/http/index.html
sed -i '$ a <a href="http://'${ip_address}':'${count}'">Start Demo</a<br/>' /srv/http/index.html
```

when I access http://localhost/cgi.sh I get

172.27.103.31

Demo started 8056 times

If I refresh I get

172.27.103.31

Demo started 8057 times

All the echo commands are working and it reads and write to my counter file correctly. However the sed commands do not run as my index.html isn't updated.

If I sh demo_start.sh from a bash prompt it works correctly. How do I get all the commands to run when I call the script via cgi?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add a `set -x` and `exec 2>&1` to the start of the shell script after the printf header to see some more debug output, or look in your logfiles. Also, there's a typo in your anchor: `</a` instead of `</a>`

Comment: Great suggestion thanks, that showed sed had a permission error in writing it temp files.